# C++ Access violation reading location when returning value in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I have a member function called `Get` as part of a matrix class structure. This matrix holds the greyscale code for each pixel of an image. The class declares a pointer to private variable

```cpp
double* matData new double[N*M];
```

Whenever I call the `Get` function I get the error:

```
ACCESS VIOLATION READING LOCATION
```

Here are the two files that I am working with:

## Matrix.h

```cpp
#ifndef MATRIX
#define MATRIX


class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double* input_data, string n);
    double Get(int i, int j) const;
    void Set(int i, int j, double val);
    ~Matrix();
private:
    int M; int N;
    string name;
    double* matData;
};


#endif
```

## Matrix.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include "matrix.h"

Matrix::Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double* input_data, string n)
{
    M = sizeR;
    N = sizeC;
    name = n;
    double* matData = new double[N*M];

    cout << "New Matrix '" << name << "' created" << endl;

    for (int ii = 0; ii<M*N; ii++)
    {
        *(matData + ii) = *(input_data + ii);
    }
}
Matrix::Get(int i, int j) const 
{
    return matData[i * N + j];
}
Matrix::Set(int i, int j, double val)
{
    matData[i*N + j] = val;
}
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    delete matData;
}
```

Can someone explain what causes this error and why it's being thrown when I'm returning what is the value at a certain point in an array at the memory location that `matData` is pointing to. Thank you!

Comment: it should be `delete[] matData`.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What you should try first may be obeying [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and trying again.

Comment: Maybe... In your constructor, you are using double * matData =... ,  which creates a new variable, not the class member. Try writing just matData = new double[N*M]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double* matData = new double[N*M];` creates a new pointer inside the constructor. The memory is leaked right away, and the member pointer is still uninitialized.

Remove the `double*` to refer to the member variable.

Answer (score 2):

The member variable `matData` isn't initialized, so dereferencing it has a big hance to cause segmentation fault.

Stop declareing local variable `matData`, which shadows the member variable, in the constructor and initialize the member variable before dereferencing it.

Other notes are:

- `delete[]` has to be used instead of `delete` for deleting what is allocated via `new[]`.
- Obey [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three): define copy constructor and assignment operator properly in order to avoid problem caused by copying pointer (not data in array).

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the reason why you are not just using `std::vector<>` which allocated and removes unused memory as you need it and it is also safe. Also it works just like any other array for example `std::vector<int> myArray;` after populating it you can use it as `myArray.at(0);` or `myArray[0];`. Also `std::vector<>` knows its size which can come in handy.